# Pseudospectrum of non square Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, eigenvalues

I have a rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import svdvals ,schur

A = np.array([[0, 2, 2,4],
              [0, 1, 2,4],
              [1, 0, 1,4],
              [0, 2, 2,4],
              [0, 1, 2,4],
              [1, 0, 1,4],
              [0, 1, 2,4],
              [1, 0, 1,4]])
A



def RECTSPA(A,grid):
    m,n = A.shape
    I = np.eye(n)
    if m >= 2*n:
        a = A[n+1:m,:]
        Q, R = np.linalg.qr(a)
        T, U = schur(a,output='real')
        R[0:n]
        T = I 
    else:
        S2, T2, Q, Z = linalg.qz(A[m-n+1,:], I[m-n+1,:])
    for z in range(1,grid):
        q,r = np.linalg.qr(z*T-S2)
        psevals = np.min(svdvals(r))
    return(psevals)
```

The code above implements the Pseudospectra which is typically computed by establishing a grid with $N$ points on a region of the complex plane, computing the resolvent norm $||(zI − A)^{−1}||$ at each grid point z, and visualizing with a contour plotter. Letting $\sigma_{max}(·)$ and $\sigma_{min}(·)$ denote the largest and smallest singular values of an input matrix, respectively, we remark that the resolvent norm satisfies

$$||(zI − A)^{−1}||_{2} =\sigma_{max}( (zI − A)^{−1})=
\frac{1}{\sigma_{min}(zI − A)} $$
Thus, one could naively compute pseudospectra by computing the SVD of $zI−A$ for each grid point $z$ and reporting the reciprocal of the smallest singular value.

The first thing to note for matrices $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n},$ $m \geq 2n$ is that although we need to compute $\sigma_{\min}(zI - A)$ at each grid point, only the upper $n \times n$ portion of this matrix changes from point to point:

$$ zI-A = \begin{pmatrix}
z \cdot I_{n} & \\
0 &
\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
A_{1} & \\
A_{2} &
\end{pmatrix}$$

Since singular values are invariant under unitary transformations, we can replace $A_{2}$ by $QA_{2}$ for any unitary matrix $Q.$ In particular, we can perform a $QR$ factorization $A_{2} = Q R,$
and then
$$\sigma_{\min}( zI-A) = \begin{pmatrix}
z \cdot I_{n} -A_{1}& \\
-A_{2}&
\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
z \cdot I_{n} - A_{1} & \\
-R &
\end{pmatrix}$$

If $R$ has any rows of zeros (as it certainly will if $m > 2n)$, these will not affect the singular values and can be removed, leaving a matrix $S$ of dimension $2n \times n$ with the following structure:

$$S= \begin{pmatrix}
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
\hline
x & x & x & x \\
 & x & x & x \\
 &  & x & x \\
 &  &  & x \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

But my code does not run.Any help?

Comment: Well, what's your question exactly?

Comment: that the code does not run due to the matrix is non square

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Are you looking for singular values of $A$? I mean: is an error in the line that you call `eigvals(A)`? If yes, it is obvious that you get errors cause non-square matrices do not have eigenvalues. You are looking for `scipy.linalg.svdvals` to get the singular values.

Comment: I am looking for eigen values since the spectrum is all the eigen values but what if I take the svdvals and square them ?

Comment: You are looking for eigenvalues of what? Eigenvalues of $A$? $A$ doesn't have any eigenvalues because it is not a square matrix. You should know that eigenvalues are defined **only** for square matrices.

Comment: I understand that non square matrices have no eigen values but the pseudo spectra some some $\varepsilon$ and beyond will find some eigen values

Comment: For clarification, I meant **pseudospectrum**, as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudospectrum.

Comment: Chapter 46 of the bible *spectra and pseudospectra* is about *rectangular pseudospectra*
https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691119465/spectra-and-pseudospectra

Comment: @Jan the algorithm is from the same author [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~trefethen/publication/PDF/2002_101.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of mistakes on sight:

```
def RECTSPA(A,grid):
    """ description: what does this do ? """
    m,n = A.shape
    I = np.eye(n)
    if m >= 2*n:
        a = A[n+1:m,:]              # ◀◀◀ A[n:], python is 0-origin
        Q, R = np.linalg.qr(a)
        T, U = schur(a,output='real')
        R[0:n]                      # ◀◀◀ noop
        T = I 
    else:
        S2, T2, Q, Z = linalg.qz(A[m-n+1,:], I[m-n+1,:])
    for z in range(1,grid):         # ◀◀◀ 1 2 ... ??
        q,r = np.linalg.qr(z*T-S2)  # ◀◀◀ S2 undefined if m >= 2n
        psevals = np.min(svdvals(r))
    return(psevals)
```

"My code does not run" questions are better asked on stackoverflow
with a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),
which this is far from.
I'd suggest start small: first Matlab
with testcases where you can check the steps,
*then* translate to Python or ... with lots of print statements.
See also 
[numpy-for-matlab-users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) 
[Norvig, Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)